# React Native: StackNavigator.... how to navigate from ListView item so another page?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I found a topic here with the same problem, but the solutions doesn't work for me.

So I have a ListView on my ScanTicketPage.js. The ListView works fine and also the onPress-function on the ListView Item which is locted in the renderRow-function.

But my Problem is, that I'm not able to navigate to another Component that is called QrCode.js. The story behind that is, that I want to tap on the list item an open a QrCode Scanner.

Maybe it's important to mention, that I use a TabNavigator that is bind in in the App.js, which also works fine.

All I can see is the alert with "press" and then nothing happens. Not Error, no warning.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  AsyncStorage,
  Keyboard,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity ,
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';

import{createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import QrCode from '../components/QrCode';




class ScanTicketPage extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Scanner List'
      };

constructor (props){
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

    this.state={
        activatedScanners:'',
        dataListSource:ds
    }

    this.goToQrCodeScreen = this.goToQrCodeScreen.bind(this);
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);

}

...

    goToQrCodeScreen=(scanner)=>{
    alert('press');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('QrCode',{
        scannerName: scanner.scannerName,
        scannerValidityEnd: scanner.scannerValidityEnd,
        scannerId: scanner.scannerId,
        dataMacroId: scanner.dataMacroId,
        hash:scanner.hash,
        requestKey: scanner.requestKey,
        })
}

renderRow(scanner, sectionId, rowId, highlightRow){

    return(
            <View >
            <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={()=>this.goToQrCodeScreen(scanner)}>
            <Text style={styles.listitem} >{scanner.scannerName} (gültig bis {scanner.scannerValidityEnd})</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

    )
}

....

render(){

  return(
    <View style={styles.viewContent}>
       <Text> Bitte wählen Sie einen Scanner aus:</Text>


       <Text>{this.state.activatedScanners}</Text>

       <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataListSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
    </View>
  );
}

const StackNavigation = createStackNavigator(
    {
    ScanTicketPage:ScanTicketPage ,
    QrCode:QrCode
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'ScanTicketPage',
      }
  );


AppRegistry.registerComponent('StackNavigation',()=> StackNavigation);
```

Answer (score 2):

"ListView" is depricated. Use "FlatList" or "SectionList".

Try with below code.

```
const StackNavigation = StackNavigator(
    {
    ScanTicketPage:  {screen: ScanTicketPage} ,
    QrCode:  {screen: QrCode},
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'ScanTicketPage',
      }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

It works. I had to change

```
export default ScanTicketPage;
```

to

```
export default StackNavigation;
```

in the ScanTicketPage.js .

Thanks MD Aslam Ansari for the hint that ListView is depricated. I'll change that later.